# Some issues with using DeepLearning4J dlls

Tags: nd4j

I am working with DeepLearning4J working with the 1.0.0-beta7 release. I am getting two errors at run time.

1. jnind4jcpu.dll unsupported jni version 0xffffffff
2. no nd4jcpu in java.library.path

I setup a path to the to a folder where I have a few other dlls for this effort. I am using java jvm 1.8.

So what version of the jvm should I use for question #1 and where in the dn4j maven project can I find the second one? I tried the uber jar for nd4j and still the same errors.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue doesn't have anything to do with the java version. Make sure you're not mixing versions of dl4j.

You don't really need to dig in to the internals or deal with any of the manual workarounds that you normally see in the jni based libraries.

All you need to do is include nd4j-native-platform in your classpath:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
</dependency>
```

Nd4j/dl4j is based on javacpp and takes care of all of that for you.
To give you even more targeted advice, I would have to know more about your environment (ideally reproducible on github)

Comment: Thanks Adam. I am working with windows 10 professional with a GTX 1080. I just rebuilt a new system and installed new GTX drivers so I am using the latest nd4j jars. I think I tried using that jar but I will recheck. Many thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I am running a web service on a app server (Wildfly) using nd4j and other related jars.

Comment: Hi Adam. I am using that jar but has no dlls just a pom. Is that expected? I got that via the maven repository.

Comment: Never mind I will use the pom inside that jar to get what you suggested.

Comment: Ok, by copying the dlls to a folder that my path variable points to solved the problem. Many thanks Adam!